# Creating a 3 column layout with in Wordpress with ACF

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I've been trying to create a simple 3 column layout using ACF. I created a group with subfields that are text areas, gave each width of 25%. They show up side by side in the editor, but on the page the text from each field spills from the container and overlaps with the other columns.

My html:

```
<?php $info = get_field('fp-blurb');?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col12 col-md-4 a1">
            <p> <?php echo $info['col1'];?> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col12 col-md-4 a2">
            <p><?php echo $info['col2'];?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col12 col-md-4 a3">
            <p> <?php echo $info['col3'];?> </p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried everything, setting the width in the plugin, setting it with css, doing the simplest possible html/css, copying code from a tutorial where it works but the text just doesn't want to line wrap. Without ACF everything works correctly, but I want to allow the user to enter their own text, instead of having it hardcoded.

EDIT: [screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/ETMgY8a) to show what's going wrong

EDIT 2: css for row and container fluid

```
.container-fluid{
    margin: 60px 0 60px;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px;
    color: white;
}

.row{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

EDIT 3: looking at it in dev tools it shows that the container is the correct size, but the text is full width.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the CSS for these container/columns on the front end?

Comment: @Ali_k Sorry, can you clarify? My css, bootstrap, js etc are all enqueued correctly and work.

Comment: I can't really evaluate this issue without seeing the current result, since bootstrap is loaded, something is not logical.

Comment: @Ali_k I've added screenshots.

Comment: That seems to be a CSS issue, try replacing `col12 col-md-4 a3` with `col-md-4` only

Comment: @Ali_k I've tried that and doing columns a few different ways(with and without bootstrap, only 2, editing width with css) and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you check these columns CSS in develop tools and share a screenshot, there is surely something in the CSS that is causing this.

Comment: @Ali_k I've added the screenshot, the columns are the correct size but the text isn't? If i'm reading it correctly.

Comment: What about `row` css and `container-fluid` css?

Comment: @Ali_k sorry, added it to the post. I've tried changing it but it doesn't affect the overflow.

Comment: @user2602540 - I think it would be great if you share the URL. so, I will check other component CSS.

Comment: @ZealousWeb I'm working on it locally but I think this should work, I'm using Local by Flywheel 524c3fd11220.ngrok.io

Comment: @ZealousWeb It fixed itself. Don't know what happened but it suddenly works. Thank you for offering help.